# discord.js bot random images

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, random, discord.js

I want to create a bot that picks a random image from an array of links, but I don't know what's wrong with it, here's the code and error

```
const arg = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
const command = arg.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'jtoh'){
  
  const rando_imgs = [
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy.gif',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy2.gif',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy3.gif',
    ]
    message.channel.send( {
      file: rando_imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * rando_imgs.length)]
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the error? :) One thing I do notice is that length in `prefix.lenght` is misspelled

Comment: it wont let me post the error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the [`send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method [accepts an object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/BaseMessageOptions) with a `files` property (not `file`). This should be an array where you can add your random image. The following will work for you:

```js
if (command === 'jtoh') {
  const rando_imgs = [
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy.gif',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy2.gif',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/CZpro4AZHs436/giphy3.gif',
  ];
  message.channel.send({
    files: [rando_imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * rando_imgs.length)]],
  });
}
```

If you want to display the message, you could just use the `content` property instead. In this case, you don't have to send an array.

```js
message.channel.send({
  content: rando_imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * rando_imgs.length)],
});
```

Also, there is a typo; `prefix.lenght` should be `prefix.length`.

```js
const arg = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
```